# Need of "runuser hdfs -s /bin/bash /bin/bash" in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I am new to `hadoop` and was following this [link](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/Hadoop) to install it in `Fedora 20`. There is a command in this article:

```
runuser hdfs -s /bin/bash /bin/bash -c "hadoop fs -mkdir /user/<name>"
```

In this part of the command we are creating a directory in the HDFS:

```
"hadoop fs -mkdir /user/<name>"
```

But I am not able to understand what is the use/meaning of this part of the above command:

```
runuser hdfs -s /bin/bash /bin/bash
```

Please let me know what is the exact use/meaning of this command:

```
runuser hdfs -s /bin/bash /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little confusing but let me try to elaborate what the command is doing:

```
runuser hdfs -s /bin/bash /bin/bash -c "hadoop fs -mkdir /user/<name>"
```

`runuser` in general is used to execute commands using specified user. You can also achieve the same thing using `su` and `sudo`, this [article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/command-line-hacks/linux-run-command-as-different-user/) explains the differences between them. `-s` option to `runuser` command specifies which shell to use to execute the specified command.

So, using the above command you are trying to execute the command:

```
/bin/bash -c "hadoop fs -mkdir /user/<name>"
```

by switching to `hdfs` user (who is the superuser for HDFS) and using `bash` shell to do so (`-s /bin/bash`). The command (`/bin/bash -c "hadoop fs ..."`) itself forces to use `/bin/bash` and pass the command as string using `-c` option.

**Alternate ways**:

You can also achieve the same thing simply by doing this as well:

```
su - hdfs -c "hadoop fs -mkdir /user/<name>"
```

or even this (which I use all the time):

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -mkdir /user/<name>
```